# InterstitialAd object is there in Admob and Facebook

Tags: facebook, admob, google-play-services, facebook-audience-network

**Background :** I am trying to have the Interstitial Ads from Admob and Facebook separately (Not via Mediation) . The facebook Ads will be triggered if the App is installed from Amazon App store.

**Question :** I need to declare the variable interstitialFromAdmob and interstitialAdFromFacebook. interstitialFromAdmob  is for the Ad from Admob and interstitialAdFromFacebook is for the Ad from Facebook. For this Admob and Facebook has used the same Object InterstitialAd. Hence I am unable to declare the variables pointing the Admob and facebook separate. Please let me know how to resolve this

```
InterstitialAd interstitialFromAdmob;

InterstitialAd interstitialAdFromFacebook;
```

Comment: does the facebook audience network work on apps downloaded from amazon app store ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common case.
For those classes have duplicated short class name, a long or full path class name shall be used.

For examples, you can use:
 
    `com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd internstitialAdFromFacebook;`